# Soap server not working in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, web-services, laravel, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to create a soap server in laravel 5.2. This is my code:
Content of `SoapController.php`:

```
<?php namespace Giant\Http\Controllers;

class SoapController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);
        ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    }

    public function server() {
        $location = url('server'); // http://payment.dev/server
        $namespace = $location;
        $class = "\\Giant\\Http\\Controllers\\HelloWorld";

        $wsdl = new \WSDL\WSDLCreator($class, $location);
        $wsdl->setNamespace($namespace);

        if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
            $wsdl->renderWSDL();
            exit;
        }

        $wsdl->renderWSDLService();

        $wsdlUrl = url('wsdl/server.wsdl');
        $server = new \SoapServer(
            url('server?wsdl'),
            array(
                'exceptions' => 1,
                'trace' => 1,
            )
        );

        $server->setClass($class);
        $server->handle();
        exit;
    }

    public function client() {
        $wsdl = url('server?wsdl');
        $client = new \SoapClient($wsdl);

        try {
            $res = $client->hello('world');
            dd($res);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            dd($ex);
        }
    }
}


class HelloWorld {
    /**
     * @WebMethod
     * @desc Hello Web-Service
     * @param string $name
     * @return string $helloMessage
     */
    public function hello($name) {
        return "hello {$name}";
    }
}
```

My wsdl file is: [wsdl](http://pastebin.com/D4QqQjWB)

And my `routes`:

```
Route::any('/server', 'SoapController@server');
Route::any('/client', 'SoapController@client');
```

And the **result** I get:

```
Internal Server Error
```

:(
I use [piotrooo/wsdl-creator](https://github.com/piotrooo/wsdl-creator) to generate wsdl. (There is no problem with that, It is working in laravel 4.2). And I have also tried nusoap and php2wsdl libraries.
My SoapClient is working well. Because it can get service from other soap servers in other urls, But I think my SoapServer can not work well.
I even get no errors in error-log file.

Comment: is this a typo error or a small error you did not see that causes you script to fail?             `array(
                'exceptions' => 1,
                'trace' => 1,
            )` should be             `array(
                'exceptions' => 1,
                'trace' => 1
            )`. If this is why you get an error then i should convert this comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out wht was the problem:
The problem with log was that i was checking error-log in my www folder while laravel has its own log file. And using that i figured that i have problem with TokenMismatchException. Laravel's CsrfVerifyMiddleware would not letting me to request using soap.
I just added my url to "except" array inside CsrfVerifyMiddleware file.

Comment: ooh, yeah, I forgot tell about it,sorry, the route must be in excpetion list

Comment: The soap calls are typically api calls, so use the routes/api.php route file. The api middleware is stateless and not use CSRF protection. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#basic-routing

Answer (score 1):

Do not use two classes in one file
This is my experience from our project in which used Soap
This is SoapServerController . Paste wsdl file in root folder of your project

`class SoapServerController extends Controller {
    public function service() {
        $server = new \SoapServer('http://' . request()->server('HTTP_HOST') . '/yourwsdlfile.wsdl');
        $server->setClass('App\Http\Requests\somenamespace\SoapRequest');
        $server->handle();
    }
}`

and in requests create class for requests like this:

`class SoapRequest{
        public function functionFromWsdl($args if you want)  {
        $parameters = (array) $args;
        return with(new fooClass())->barMethod($parameters);
       }
    }`

and route must be post:

`Route::post('webservice','SoapServerController@service');`

Comment: Thank you @Faradox. But that did not help me. This is my [controller](http://pastebin.com/V1STP9xF), my [wsdl](http://pastebin.com/Cix5EaS6), my [SoapRequest class](http://pastebin.com/8HY0C7sf), my [SoapClinet](http://pastebin.com/Ckp80xAW) (in a pure php script). and my route: ```Route::any('webservice','SoapServerController@service');```

Comment: I get "Internal server error" when i call method in soap server. And there is no log in error_log file and i do not know what is the cause of error.

Comment: I have also tried to call soap-server in non-wsdl mode. And the same problem.

Comment: problem with your wsdl

Comment: try like this in service method  `` $server = new \SoapServer('http://' . request()->server('HTTP_HOST') . '/yourwsdlfile.wsdl');``

Comment: If you set debug mode to true you should see a stack trace.

After getting it to work on my machine i found that your `internal server error` originates here: https://github.com/piotrooo/wsdl-creator/blob/master/src/WSDL/Service/Service.php#L74

You should probably keep the HelloWorld class in a separate file.

Comment: Can parameter of `setClass` be  `App\Http\Requests\somenamespace\SoapRequest`?

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 5 all before statements have turned into middlewares (just like what is in django framework). And you need to implement using middlewares.

Comment: I checked the laravel 5 documents. You are right @Sirbito. Thanks a lot.